# DB structure for users of different groups and fields

Tags: mysql, database, structure

There are two types of customers, it's individual and corporate customers.
For example they have same fields (email, password), but corporate customers has unique fields (company name, company phone, address).
What else could be the structure of the database?

```
mysql> desc `customers`;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id_customer | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| email       | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password    | int(16)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc `corporate_customers`;
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id_customer     | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| company_name    | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| company_address | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Can be used next db structure?".

Comment: I mean is this only one way to solve this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not the only way to build your tables.  If you are looking for other suggestions. You might consider a "person" table, a "company" table, and a "customer" table and two many to many tables called "person_customer" and "company_customer".

```
"PERSON"
  person_ID, PK
  email
  password
"Company"
  company_id, PK
  company_name
  company_address
"Customer"
  id_customer, PK
"person_customer"
  person_ID, FK
  id_customer, FK
"company_customer"
  company_id, FK
  id_customer, FK
```

That example gives you a distinct Customer object, and distinct person and company objects. The problem that I see with your example is that you have "id_customer" as a primary key in two different tables. I would consider that bad form. How you build the tables is up to you, but I see a problem with that.

Comment: But you are not saying why this is a bad form? It's will be interesting for me, cause i'm using same structure in different situations.

Comment: If you ask me, it's just confusing. When someone needs to lookup a customer by id_customer...how do they know which table to look at? That ID could be in customers, or it could be in company_customers. Or, imagine this - "John Doe" id_customer: 1. And then, "Pepsi Corporation" id_customer: 1. You lose a little bit of integrity when id_customer: X can represent one of two records.

Comment: Thanks for comment, i will notice this

Answer (score 0):

You could be more specific on what you are trying to accomplish. There is no problem whit the database structure of course but your not specifying anything.

If you are trying to do something like checking which id's match from the 2 tables and selecting `company_name , company_address` here's how but how I was saying you could be more specific about what you want.

```
SELECT corporate_customers.company_name ,corporate_customers.company_address FROM corporate_customers WHERE corporate_customers.id_customer = customers.id_customer
```

Answer (score 0):

This works. Only thing in addition you may want to do in `corporate_customers` table is to add a `unique constraint` as below:

```
  CONSTRAINT uc_corporate_customers UNIQUE (company_name,company_address)
```

This will make sure there are no duplicate compnay_name and company_address for a customer.

Comment: I have primary key on id_customer

Comment: @uint `Being a primary key, its always(has to) unique`. Above constraint will stop two corporate customers from having same company name and address.

Comment: But how two different customers can have two same company name and address?)

Comment: @uint What if you/user try/tries to insert such data? I am just trying to share my feedback about your structure. Data structures are created to serve the needs as well as to safeguard the data if possible. If you are saying, corporate_customers will have unique `company_name,company_address..`, an unique constraint should be added so that you can't insert records with duplicate details.